# Why do I get AttributeError. Its not working

Tags: python, class, object, python-3.x, attributes

```
class Bil(object):
    def __init__(self, tankVol, aktVol=0):
        self.tankVolym = tankVol
        self.aktuellVolym = aktVol

    def tanka(self, liter=5):
        self.aktuellVolym = self.aktuellVolym + liter
        over = self.aktuellVolym - self.tankVolym
        if over > 0 :
            self.aktuellVolym = self.tankVolym
        else:
            over = 0
        return over

print(Bil.tanka(80))
print(Bil.aktuellVolym)
```

Why will it not work?

```
AttributeError:
    "int" object as no attribute "aktuellVolym"
```

Comment: Bil is a class. You will need an instance of that class -> foobar = Bil(20). And then you are able to use foobar.aktuellVolym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bil` is a class.  I think you want an *instance* of the class instead.

```
bil_instance = Bil(80)  # Create instance of Bil.
print(bil_instance.tanaka())
print(bil_instance.aktuellVolym)
```

---

In this case, you're getting an `AttributeError` because:

```
Bil.tanka(80)
```

passes `80` as the `self` argument to your `tanka` function.  On python2.x, you would have gotten a different error saying that `tanka` needs a `Bil` instance as the first argument.